# How to append a sentence with prefix and suffix in java?

Tags: java, string

I am trying to read an input file that contains the following:

**input.txt**

```
Hello world. Welcome,
to the java.
```

And, I have to append the sentence with prefix(BEGIN) and suffix(END) and the output should like the following:

**output expected:**

```
BEGIN_Hello world_END.BEGIN_ Welcome,
to the java_END.
```

Following is my input file reading function. I am reading an entire file and storing it in array list:
**InputDetails.java**

```
private List<String> readInput = new ArrayList<>();
public void readFile() throws IOException {
   while((inputLine = input.readLine()) != null ) {
      readInput.add(inputLine);
   }
}

//Getter to return input file content
public List<String> getReadInput() {
   return readInput;
}
```

And following is my code for appending the string with **BEGIN** and **END**:

```
public void process() {
   InputDetails inputD = new InputDetails();
   for(int i=0;i<inputD.getReadInput().size();i++) {
            String sentence = inputD.getReadInput().get(i);
            String splitSentence[] = sentence.split("\\.");
            for(int j=0;j<splitSentence.length;j++) {
                System.out.println(splitSentence[j]);
                splitSentence[j] = "BEGIN_"+splitSentence[j]+"__END";
            }
            sentence = String.join(".",splitSentence);
            inputD.writeToFile(sentence);
        }
}
```

**output getting:**

```
BEGIN_SENTENCE__Hello world__END_SENTENCE.BEGIN_SENTENCE__Welcome
to the java.
```

**Note:** Each sentence is separated by a "." (period) character. The output Sentence should be prefixed with BEGIN_ and suffixed with __END. The period character is not considered a part of the sentence. And, input file are delimited by one or more spaces. The sentence is complete when it has period(.) Even if it means the sentence completes on the new line(just as the input that i specified above). All, the special chars position should be retained in the output. There can also be a space between period(.) or a comma(,) and a word. **for eg:** java . or Welcome ,

Can Anyone help me fix this? Thanks

Comment: `split` at `.` and then `join` again on it after appending the prefix and suffix for each element. So `String[] sentences = text.split("\\.");` and then a regular for loop over the array with some `sentences[i] = prefix + sentences[i] + suffix;` and finally `String text = String.join(".", sentences);`, done.

Comment: @Zabuzard, It's not working. it's displaying as: BEGIN_Hello world__END.BEGIN_ Welcome,__END
BEGIN_to the java__END

Comment: Sounds to me that you used a different code than what i proposed that also splits on comma and not just dot. Hard to say without seeing your code.

Comment: It's the same code as above. Nothing different.

Comment: No, I mean you attempt to use my code. Apparently you must have used it wrong since it works for me.

Comment: @Zabuzard, See I have edited the code above. please check.

Comment: Thats not the fault of the split+join. It is because that is where you finish the iteration and move to the next entry in the list returned by `getReadInput()`. You can not use this code if you keep the input separated into multiple strings. You first have to merge it to a single string or at least have it separated only on sentences-bounds. Unfortunately you did not really explain how exactly you want to handle all the edge cases regarding those split lines.

Comment: so, how should i do it. can you help?

Comment: I already told you everything, you have to explain in more detail what you want. The proposed answer solves your problem by guessing that you want to concate all your lines first. You never explained whether thats what you want though, so we can not help without guessing. You have to explain the expected behavior first.

Comment: Instead of commenting, please [edit] your question. The comment section is not meant to *chat*. You should prepare your question in a way that it does not need follow-up questions and ping-pong directly in the first place before you post it.

Answer (score 1):

First, you'll need to join your string list input into a single string. Then, you can use the `String.split()` method to break up your input into parts delimited by the `.` character. You can then choose to either run a loop on that array or use the stream method (as shown below) to iterate over your sentences. On each part, simply append the required `BEGIN_` and `_END` blocks to the sentence. You can use manual string concatenation using the `+` operator or use a string template with `String.format()` (as shown below). Finally, reintroduce the `.` delimiter used to break the input by joining the parts back into a single string.

```
String fullString = String.join("", getReadInput());
Arrays.asList(fullString).split("\\.")).stream()
  .map(s -> String.format("BEGIN_%s_END", s))
  .collect(Collectors.joining("."));
```

Comment: Could you also add some explanation?